# Can you configure your mouse to move to second screen regardless of scale and monitor location

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've found this to be a hard question to google for. Trust me, I tried. When i'm in "1" and want to move cursor to "2" and I have to find the corner, it's super annoying.

Is there a way to tell the system to move the mouse to the top of "2" if I try to move from 1 anywhere above where 2 meets 1? For example, if I moved over to 2 near where I've placed the ? in my awesome diagram. Is there 3rd party software that can handle this?

```
----------
|  1(4K) |?
|        |---------
|        |2(1080P)|
|        |        |
-------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

The computer has no idea what the physical size of each monitor is, it can only see its resolution.

You can only traverse between screens inside the pixel count that you have lined up in your display preferences, the rest has no corresponding partner screen to move to… it's a brick wall, in effect.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. I'm kind of a programmer but really just a scripter. Do you think it's theoretically possible to write an application that solves this problem? I'd love to try lol. Define monitor edges and mouse placements.

Comment: You'd imagine if it was possible, someone would have done it already. I don't know of any app or utility that can do this.

Comment: I'd understand if it was 'really complicated but doable', but impossible? I don't see how it could be impossible considering all of the things we can do.