# How to force macOS to properly detect screen size when using it with an external display?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I use a big external monitor with a MacBook Pro. Resolution configs and font sizes, etc. work great. The only issue I have is with arranging the displays when using an external display.

I have the MacBook Pro below the monitor, so top left corner of the MacBook Pro screen is “aligned” with the bottom left corner of the external monitor. If I arrange the displays this way, the mouse pointer passes precisely on the left side, but on the right side I might have a difference of up to 5-10 inches.

Is there any way to get the OS to properly interpret the display sizes so that the mouse integration between extended displays gets more precise?

Comment: Not unless they're not only the same size but also the same resolution. The computer only sees the resolution. See https://superuser.com/questions/1558218/can-you-configure-your-mouse-to-move-to-second-screen-regardless-of-scale-and-mo {i'm sure there are others, but my google-fu is failing me]

Comment: I seem to remember from the Windows world that it was possible to resize the monitor on the arrange screen... It would be so easy to type in the measures of the monitor and allow the OS to make a simple calculation... This would really be a great feature... Too bad it is done with resolution only...

Comment: The computer does actually know exactly what display is connected & what physical size it is, but chooses to completely disregard that information for this purpose. I've never known any utility on any platform that could compensate for this.